# Tracking a mobile number using GPS

Tags: android, eclipse, gps

I am trying to develop an application in android using eclipse .
This application is like finding the friend location and directions using android mobile .

Now my idea to do this is in three steps :
1. tracing the mobile number of friend if he is having the GPS connectivity .
2. then putting that location(latitude, longitude) in Google maps with your location .
3. Google maps gives us the directions and this way we get it (using Google Map key ).

2nd and 3rd steps are done but the I am not able to figure out how to do the 1st part .

Sudhanshu

Answer (score 1):

The user that you want to track needs to install and run an application, that regularly posts the GPS coordinates to your server.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct support for Step 1, due to obvious reasons.

I would suggest that you use a more legitimate way, by using the [Google Latitude api.](http://code.google.com/apis/latitude/v1/using_rest.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
tracing the mobile number of friend if he is having the GPS connectivity
```

IMHO the easiest and best way is to

1. generate a uniqueID per install.
2. read the location of  that user  at some regular interval
3. and posting the GPS coordinates to your server from the client application.